# Reshape blocks without breaking walls

Tags: terraria

Cannot for the life of me find *anything* about this *anywhere*. When hammering blocks to reshape them, the hammer will almost always destroy walls simultaneously. This seems to be especially true with stronger hammers like The Axe or Luminite hamaxes. Since I don't *want* to break the walls, I have to replace them one-by-one making for a very tedious process.

**Is there any way to reshape blocks without breaking the wall behind them?** Preferably without having to use a wooden hammer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hammers and their interaction with walls is definitely one of the more annoying aspects of building in Terraria. Unfortunately, there's not really a good fix.

If I recall correctly, hammering a tile seems to be pixel-perfect. That is, if you click on a transparent part of the block (the "air" of a triangle shaped tile, for example), the wall behind that block will be affected instead. Additionally, wall-tiles themselves actually extend into the neighboring tiles, making their "hitbox" much larger than a single tile. Therefore, you need to be careful where you click when working with hammers. In particular, make sure that smart-targeting is turned off, as this can occasionally target tiles and walls that you don't want to touch.

In my experience, high-tier hammers not not really useful for **con**struction - they are much better suited for **de**struction. This is because with the highest tiers of hammer, a single mouse click often lasts long enough to get two or three ticks of hammer action in before the click releases. If you're looking to put the finishing touches on a structure, I would recommend using a lower-tier hammer, perhaps Adamantium/Titanium or less, so that single clicks equate to single hammer actuations.

Comment: Not quite the golden hotkey I was looking for but I guess Re-Logic just really dropped the ball on hammers and haven't picked it up yet. Although I don't think the "pixel perfect" thing really applies since I've tried it and walls _will_ be mined through blocks even in areas with overlap between shapes. If only _every single hammer_ didn't autoswing.

Comment: Just use a wooden hammer.